# Problema con ejercicio básico de tratado de Strings

Tags: java

El ejercicio consiste en introducir una frase y que la trate de modo que sustituya las letras que están en el Array y en la frase por la letra que está en el Array + 2. Es decir, si el array fuese de a, b, c y d y la frase fuese bajo debería devolver dcjo, y si la frase fuese dado debería devolver bcbo.

Llevo ya una hora delante del código y no sé qué hago mal para que sólo lo haga con la última letra que tiene que sustituir. Gracias de antemano.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    final static ArrayList letrasArray = new ArrayList<>();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String frase = "", resultado = "";
        inicializarLetras(letrasArray);
        System.out.println("Introduce frase a traducir");
        frase = br.readLine();
        resultado = traducir(frase);
        System.out.println("El resultado de su frase traducida es:\n-->" + resultado);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void inicializarLetras(ArrayList<Character> letrasArray) {
    letrasArray.add('m');
    letrasArray.add('n');
    letrasArray.add('s');
    letrasArray.add('r');
    letrasArray.add('l');
    letrasArray.add('t');
    letrasArray.add('p');
    letrasArray.add('d');
    letrasArray.add('b');
}

private static String traducir(String frase) {
    String res = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
        char letraActual = frase.charAt(i);

        if (letrasArray.contains(letraActual)){
            int indexLetra = letrasArray.indexOf(letraActual);
            if ((letrasArray.size() - indexLetra) == 1)
                indexLetra = 1;
            else if ((letrasArray.size() - indexLetra) == 2)
                indexLetra = 0;
            res=frase.replace(letraActual, letrasArray.get(indexLetra + 2));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    final static ArrayList<Character> letrasArray = new    ArrayList<Character>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String frase = "", resultado = "";
        inicializarLetras(letrasArray);
        System.out.println("Introduce frase a traducir");
        frase = br.readLine();
        resultado = traducir(frase);
        System.out.println("El resultado de su frase traducida es:\n-->" + resultado);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void inicializarLetras(ArrayList<Character> letrasArray) {
    letrasArray.add('m');
    letrasArray.add('n');
    letrasArray.add('s');
    letrasArray.add('r');
    letrasArray.add('l');
    letrasArray.add('t');
    letrasArray.add('p');
    letrasArray.add('d');
    letrasArray.add('b');
}

private static String traducir(String frase) {
    String res = frase;
    for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
        char letraActual = Character.toLowerCase(frase.charAt(i));
        if (letrasArray.contains(letraActual)){
            System.out.println("Letra Actual:" + letraActual);
            int indexLetra = letrasArray.indexOf(letraActual);
            if ((letrasArray.size() - indexLetra) == 1)
                indexLetra = 1;
            else if ((letrasArray.size() - indexLetra) == 2)
                indexLetra = 0;
            res=res.replace(letraActual, letrasArray.get(indexLetra + 2));
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: Solo es cuestion de que trabajes con el mismo String ya que en cada iteracion, y cada vez que entra a tu if el String res volvia a tomar el valor de frase, por eso al fina se veia reflejado solo en la ultima letra.

Comment: ¡Gracias, esto sí me funcionó! :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu duda/problema no esta bien detallada, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta para que sea clara y precisa.

Rápidamente veo las siguientes cosas:

En tu `main()`, `letrasArray` no está declarado, no existe.

En tu método `traducir()`, `letrasArray` tampoco existe.

Debes declararlas localmente o globalmente.

Por qué no usas `Scanner` en lugar de `BufferedReader`?.

Basándome en tu código, algo como esto te podría ayudar mejor (no es la solución final):

```
// La clase Scanner se encuentra en el paquete java.util por lo tanto se debe incluir al inicio del programa la instrucción
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String frase = "";

        // La clase Scanner está disponible a partir de Java 5 y facilita la lectura de datos en los programas Java
        // Tenemos que crear un objeto de la clase Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce frase a traducir: ");
        frase = sc.nextLine();  // Leer un String

        System.out.println("El resultado de su frase traducida es:\n--> " + traducir(frase));

    }

    // Método para traducir
    static String traducir(String frase) {

        // Llenamos el array de letras
        char[] arrayLetras;
        arrayLetras = "a".toCharArray();
        arrayLetras = "b".toCharArray();
        arrayLetras = "c".toCharArray();
        arrayLetras = "d".toCharArray();

        // Convertimos la frase recibida en un array de char
        char[] arrayFrase = frase.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++) {
            if (arrayFrase[i] == arrayLetras[i]) {
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(arrayFrase);
    }

}
```